# Hotel Booking Single Date selection PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to edit WordPress Traveler Theme where they have Checkin and Checkout Date selection by just single date selection and I'm having issues with it. I already removed the checkout section but when clicking on the Arrival / Departure it still shows multiple date selection. How can I make it a single date?

**https://taskchimps.com/hotels/st_hotel/graace-hotel/**

[image: https://taskchimps.com/hotels/st_hotel/graace-hotel/]

```
<?php
$start = STInput::get('start', date(TravelHelper::getDateFormat()));
$end = STInput::get('end', date(TravelHelper::getDateFormat(), strtotime("+ 1 day")));
$date = STInput::get('date', date('d/m/Y h:i a'). '-'. date('d/m/Y h:i a', strtotime('+1 day')));
$has_icon = (isset($has_icon))? $has_icon: false;
?>
<div class="form-group form-date-field date-enquire form-date-search clearfix <?php if($has_icon) echo ' has-icon '; ?>" data-format="<?php echo TravelHelper::getDateFormatMoment() ?>">
    <?php
        if($has_icon){
            echo TravelHelper::getNewIcon('ico_calendar_search_box');
        }
    ?>
    <div class="date-wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="check-in-wrapper">
             <div class="st-item-date">
                 <label><?php echo __('Arrival / Departure', 'traveler'); ?></label>
                        <div class="render check-in-render"><?php echo esc_html($start); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="check-in-input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($start) ?>" name="start">
    <input type="text" class="check-in-out" value="<?php echo esc_attr($date); ?>" name="date">
</div>
```

Comment: you have to make changes in the datepicker JS initialiser. Here is the datepicker that is used: https://www.daterangepicker.com/ It's all very clear in the docs

Comment: Thank you for your comment @CornelRaiu I'll check it